# Azure 1-hour Web App try - SQL Compact db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, sql-server-ce

I have ASP.NET MVC web app which uses Entity Framework and Compact DB - "db.sdf" or "db.mdf" file.

It work at localhost.

But I want to publish it to Azure as 1-hour try web app.

I got this error:

> The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application.

What is going on? I have installed packages:

```
EF.SqlServer
EF.SqlServerCompact
System.Data.SqlServerCe
```

And the web.config looks:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework"
             type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, 
         EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
         PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data 
     Source=|DataDirectory|db.sdf" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
</connectionStrings>

<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>

<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
        <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" 
             invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" 
             description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" 
             type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, 
              System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
           PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Comment: "*But I want to publish it to Azure as 1-hour try web app*" - not sure what this means.

Comment: Maybe you need to make the file "Copy To Local" - to do this, open references, click on SqlServerCe.4.0 and in the properties window choose Copy To Local. That will make sure that the file is part of the deployment package.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to check whether SQL Compact database could work on Azure Web App? I just test it on my Web App. It can work fine. You could use it for development environment. For production environment, we suggest you [Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/).

> 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0' could not be loaded.

To use SQL Compact in .NET application, we need to install following packages from NuGet.

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact
EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact
```

After that, following 2 .NET assemblies and multi native assemblies will be referenced by your application.

[image]

[image]

For your issue, please check whether the copy local property is set to 'true' for the 2 .NET assemblies.

[image]

Before using SQL Compact, you need to configure connection string in web.config as following.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\myDB.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
```

After that, you could use SQL Compact by EF. Code below is for your reference.

```
public class MyDataContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDataContext():base("DefaultConnection") { }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext();
    context.Students.Add(new Student() { ID = 1, Name = "name1" });
    context.SaveChanges();
    return Content("Create data OK!");
}
```

If you use code first model, you also need to create App_Data folder under wwwroot folder after deploying your web application to Azure Web App if this folder is not created by default.

Comment: Any updates? Is your issue solved, If yes, please mark helpful replies as answer. If you have further questions, please feel free to let me know.